# Does music21 include a note transition counter?

Tags: python, music21

I'm trying to get transition rates between note pitches (just name, no octave) in a given melody.
For example, if my melody pitches are (in order) C D E D F C B C, I should get that the C-D transition occurs with 0.5 rate, B-C has rate 1, etc.

I should be able to write a function in Python to do this (probably using a lot of `elifs`...) but it looks like music21 must be able to do it easily too. I looked at the documentation, Google, other questions here... and I couldn't find how, but I suspect I'm missing a toolkit that may be really useful for me.

Comment: I don't understand the example transition rates you give: *why* does C-D have rate 0.5 and *why* does B-C have rate 1?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you will have to write this function yourself. I can't see that music21 provides this already.

Comment: Ok. About the first question, C-D means "transition from C to D", assuming you are in C. In the example, one transition starting in C went to D, and the other yo B. So I give both transitions the same probability. But if you start at B, in the example there is only one transition (B-C), so the rate is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing something like:

```
from music21.ext.more_itertools import windowed
from collections import Counter
# assuming s is your Stream
nameTuples = []
for n1, n2 in windowed(s.recurse().notes, 2):
    nameTuples.append((n1.name, n2.name))
c = Counter(nameTuples)
totalNotes = len(s.recurse().notes) # py2 cast to float
{k : v / totalNotes for k, v in c.items()}
```

Nice thing about windowed is that it's easy to create Trigrams, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you may be looking for is a kind of bigram representation, which I typically handle with dictionaries. This may be a tad sloppy, but you can probably easily tidy it up:

```
note_list = ...a list containing all notes in order
bigram_dict = {}
for note in range(1, len(note_list)):
    bigram = (note -1, note)
    if bigram not in bigram_dict:
        bigram_dict[bigram] = 1 / len(note_list)
    else:
        bigram_dict[bigram] += 1 / len(note_list)
```

This will give you the percents of each bigram. If using Python 2.x, you will have to make `bigram_dict[bigram += float(1 / len(note_list))` to avoid integer/float issues. Also, if the dictionary gives you trouble, you can try using defaultdict.